# multer npm: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I have a problem uploading an image file to my server, I watched a tutorial on YouTube about multer and I do exactly the same thing that is done in the tutorial and for whatever reason I get an error: ("TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"). I googled for the error and found some people having the same issue and I tried to solve it like them, but it didn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/images/profilePictures');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

app.use(express.static('public'))
```

the Image Schema and model:

```
const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    profilePicture: String
})

const Image = new mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema)
```

My post route:

```
app.post('/changeProfilePic', upload.single('profilePicture'), function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.file);
   const newImage = new Image({
       profilePicture: req.file.path
   })
   newImage.save()
})
```

My html upload form:

```
<form action="/changeProfilePic" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="profilePicture" placeholder="Image" />
      <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

and when I logged the value of (req.file) it says that its type is 'undefined', so that must mean that multer didn't recognize or even didn't received the image file. what am I doing wrong that multer doesn't get the file?

Comment: Hi, you have unneeded spaces around `=` sign in `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`, try changing to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: There could be a problem in the filename you give the file, causing multer to fail and not attaching the file property to the request object. Neither Linux nor Windows support filenames with colons in them, which `new Date().toISOString()` produces.

Comment: @Vitalii Hello, I changed it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JimNilsson. I removed the new ``` Date().toISOString() ``` still multer doesn't recognize the req.file

Comment: Have you also made sure the directory `./public/images/profilePictures` exists, and that the path is correct?

Comment: @JimNilsson this is my directory: ("Project/( this is where the app.js is) public/images/profilePictures") yes this directory exist but i'm not sure if I wrote that code accurately

Comment: @Pengin Show us tree structure of your directory.

Comment: @RichardRublev D:\Coding\Store\public\images\profilePictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the destination to `./uploads` works fine for me